# echo ucfirst tag name

Tags: php, wordpress, tags, ucfirst

on my website I want to display all tags associated with a post.
here is my code :

```
<?php

$posttags = get_the_tags();

if ($posttags): ?>

<?php foreach($posttags as $tag): ?>

<a href="<?php echo get_tag_link($tag); ?>" title="<?php echo $tag->name; ?> - Re Active"><?php echo $tag->name; ?></a>

<?php endforeach; endif; ?>
```

what I'm trying to do is to capitalize the title

```
<?php echo ucfirst($tag->name); ?>
```

but it's not working...

any idea of what I'm doing wrong ?

thanks

Comment: Don't you want it in `<?php echo $tag->name; ?>` too? Also, you need to `echo` the first one.

Comment: What's not working? Be more specific

Comment: As Jon Stirling says, you're only applying it to the title attribute, but also check you've not got CSS `text-transform:lowercase;` applied too somewhere

Comment: Capitalize the title? You mean fullcaps?

Comment: @JonStirling sorry I corrected my code

Comment: @EatPeanutButter the problem is that I want the first letter of my title to be capitalized, but it's not working.

Comment: @PhilS I know how to use capitalize with css, but this is not a css trouble. I need to echo the title with first capital letter

Comment: Do you want to capitalize the text in the title attribute or the text that actually displays to the user in the link?

Comment: @EatPeanutButter the text in the title attribute "echo ucfirst ($tag->name)

Comment: @EatPeanutButter when echoing $tag->name, I get for example paris. I want to get Paris

Comment: In your code, there are 2 places you echo the tag name.  One is in the title attribute, which usually only displays in the tooltip on hover. The other displays the actual link.  You need to add ucfirst() to both of them.  Have  you done that?  If so, update the code in your question.

Comment: @EatPeanutButter no i only add ucfirst to the title attribute. for the other one I used CSS. In fact your right, when I add ucfirst to both of them it works. can you please explain me why ?

Comment: ucfirst() does not change the value of the variable you pass in.  It only formats a copy of the original variable, and the original variable stays unchanged.  And your CSS wouldn't target any text inside a title attribute

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138959/discussion-between-mmdwc-and-eatpeanutbutter).